# IIS 7 URL Rewrite Module

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, asp-classic, url-rewriting

I can see the Outbound URL Rewrite working, because it replaces all the URL's on the page with the new URL.  So wherever I put this:

`/post.asp?topic=question&id=123`

it rewrites it to...

`/question/123`

But, when I visit the rewritten URL `/question/123` I get a 404 error.  It looks like the rewriting part works, but how about loading the URL once you goto the rewritten URL?

I used the 'Create Friendly URL' wizard in IIS > URL Rewriting and checked the Outbound and Redirect rule as well., just like this example explains: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/497/user-friendly-url---rule-template/

Here is the Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <remove name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" />
                <remove name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" />
                <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^post\.asp$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^topic=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;id=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"  />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/post.asp?topic={R:1}&amp;id={R:2}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <remove name="OutboundRewriteUserFriendlyURL1" />
                <rule name="OutboundRewriteUserFriendlyURL1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^(.*/)/post\.asp\?topic=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;(?:amp;)?id=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;(?:amp;)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}{R:2}/{R:3}/" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you post your rewrite route configuration from your web.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you modified the pattern(s)? I've created rules with same steps using wizard. However my configuration file is different than yours, it works smoothly. Compare the patterns, especially for **OutboundRewriteUserFriendlyURL1**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^post\.asp$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^topic=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;id=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="post.asp?topic={R:1}&amp;id={R:2}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="OutboundRewriteUserFriendlyURL1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^(.*/)post\.asp\?topic=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;(?:amp;)?id=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}{R:2}/{R:3}/" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```